# Difference between Stagers, stages and singles

Tags: linux, payload, metasploit

Using msfconsole and searched for linux x64 payloads.

I came across stagers, stages and singles? They all have 'reverse_tcp' in them which reverses the connection back to the attacker. However I tried looking up the differences between stagers, stages and singles, they seem similar but different. I still don't understand.

Anyone able to explain whats the difference between them so I know which one to use?

Answer (score 1):

The *staged* payload is send in two parts to the victim. The first part is a small primary payload that do that the victim machine connect to the attacker machine and later the attack machine sends the second part of the payload. It is useful when the buffer has not a big length. (eg. linux/x64/shell/reverse_tcp)

The *non-staged (single)* payload is send entire the shellcode to the victim. It needs a buffer length bigger. (linux/x64/shell_reverse_tcp)